# Savon `set_auth': wrong number of arguments (2 for 3) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

running `ruby file.rb`, gives me `.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient.rb:535:in 'set_auth': wrong number of arguments (2 for 3) (ArgumentError)`

file.rb:

```
require 'savon'

url = 'https://website.com/services/'
login = Base64.strict_encode64("2111:232330:OunOi28")

client = Savon.client(
  endpoint: url,
  namespace: url,
  log: true,
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  basic_auth: "Basic #{login}"
  )
response = client.call(:something)
```

Note: I have to send 3 credentials, currently passing them in the login variable.

How can I define this `set_auth` in the client or the call on the client?

Stacktrace:

```
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:54:in 'setup_auth' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:43:in 'setup_client' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb:25:in
'request' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi.rb:161:in 'request' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/httpi-2.4.1/lib/httpi.rb:133:in 'post' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in 'block in call_with_logging'

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in 'call' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/request_logger.rb:12:in 'log' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:94:in 'call_with_logging'
from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/operation.rb:54:in 'call' 

from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.6/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/client.rb:36:in 'call' 

from file.rb:18:in '<main>'
```

Comment: Please attach the full backtrace and specify the savon version.

Comment: @eug.nikolaev stacktrace added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not need to pass an **Array** to the `:basic_auth` parameter, i.e.:

```
client = Savon.client(
  endpoint: url,
  namespace: url,
  log: true,
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  basic_auth: [login, password] # (Whatever the password is??)
)
```

The error comes from [here](https://github.com/savonrb/httpi/blob/2c0a725dc055dce689defa39399b3e41c88b2c11/lib/httpi/adapter/httpclient.rb#L51) in the source code; it is expecting an array of a username and password.

See the [Authentication section of the documentation](http://savonrb.com/version2/globals.html) for correct usage:

> ## Authentication
>
> HTTP authentication will be used for retrieving remote WSDL documents
>   and actual SOAP requests.
>
> ### basic_auth
>
> Savon supports HTTP basic authentication.
>
> `Savon.client(basic_auth: ["luke", "secret"])`
>
> [...]